# Counting latest state of stateful entities in streaming with Flink

Tags: scala, analytics, apache-flink, bigdata

I tried to create my first real-time analytics job in Flink. The approach is kappa-architecture-like, so I have my raw data on Kafka where we receive a message for every change of state of any entity.

So the messages are of the form:

```
(id,newStatus, timestamp)
```

We want to compute, for every time window, the count of items in a given status. So the output should be of the form:

```
(outputTimestamp, state1:count1,state2:count2 ...)
```

or equivalent. These rows should contain, at any given time, the count of the items in a given status, where the status associated to an Id is the most recent message observed for that id. The status for an id should be counted in any case, even if the event is way older than those getting processed. So the sum of all the counts should be equal to the number of different IDs observed in the system. The following step could be forgetting about the items in a final item after a while, but this is not a strict requirement right now.

This will be written on elasticsearch and then queried.

I tried many different paths and none of them completely satisfied the requirement. Using a sliding window I could easily achieve the expected behaviour, except that when the beginning of the sliding window surpassed the timestamp of an event, it was lost for the count, as you may expect. Others approaches failed to be consistent when working with a backlog because I did some tricks with keys and timestamps that failed when the data was processed all at once.

So I would like to know, even at an high level, how should I approach this problem. It looks like a relatively common use-case but the fact that the relevant information for a given ID must be retained indefinitely to count the entities correctly creates a lot of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have a solution for your problem:

Given a `DataStream` of `(id, state, time)` as:

```
val stateUpdates: DataStream[(Long, Int, ts)] = ???
```

You derive the actual state changes as follows:

```
val stateCntUpdates: DataStream[(Int, Int)] = s // (state, cntUpdate)
  .keyBy(_._1) // key by id
  .flatMap(new StateUpdater)
```

`StateUpdater` is a stateful `FlatMapFunction`. It has a keyed state that stores the last state of each id. For each input record it returns two state count update records: `(oldState, -1)`, `(newState, +1)`. The `(oldState, -1)` record ensures that counts of previous states are reduced.

Next you aggregate the state count changes per state and window:

```
val cntUpdatesPerWindow: DataStream[(Int, Int, Long)] = stateCntUpdates // (state, cntUpdate, time)
  .keyBy(_._1) // key by state
  .timeWindow(Time.minutes(10)) // window should be non-overlapping, e.g. Tumbling
  .apply(new SumReducer(), new YourWindowFunction())
```

`SumReducer` sums the cntUpdates and `YourWindowFunction` assigns the timestamp of your window. This step aggregates all state changes for each state in a window.

Finally, we adjust the current count with the count updates.

```
val stateCnts: DataStream[(Int, Int, Long)] = cntUpdatesPerWindow // (state, count, time)
  .keyBy(_._1) // key by state again
  .map(new CountUpdater)
```

`CountUpdater` is a stateful `MapFunction`. It has a keyed state that stores the current count for each state. For each incoming record, the count is adjusted and a record `(state, newCount, time)` is emitted.

Now you have a stream with new counts for each state (one record for each state). If possible, you can update your Elasticsearch index using these records. If you need to collect all state counts for a given time you can do that using a window.

**Please note**: The state size of this program depends on the number of unique ids. That might cause problems if the id space grows very fast.

Comment: I'm working with your suggestions, thank you very much. What I'm missing here is what `YourWindowFunction` should do. I have no notion of event time there and so I can't assign a timestamp. Also this solution seems to be working by processing time, while I care about event time. I couldn't make it run yet but for what I got, this is slightly different from what I need.

Comment: This works with event-time as well. You need to set the right `TimeCharacteristics` on the exec env and assign timestamps + watermarks. The only time dependend operation is the window. `YourWindowFunction` assigns the timestamp of the window. `WindowFunction.apply()` has a `TimeWindow` parameter that gives access to the window's start and end time. See [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/windows.html#windowfunction-with-incremental-aggregation).

Comment: The `TimeCharacteristics` was already set but I don't know how to assign the timestamp with this layout? Should I bring the timestamp along with the updates? Something like (status, count, timestamp)?

Comment: I did it this way. I don't want to say it works yet but it is resistant to every problematic we met until now. Thanks a lot Fabian. I hope this solution holds.

Comment: I think the timestamps should simply be the timestamps of the initial change rows. Watermarks depend on the characteristics of your source.